# Suppress frame title when using allowframebreaks in beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I suppress the title completely on the continuation slides when using `allowframebreaks` in beamer?

In the example below, Title should only appear on the first slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\
\framebreak
B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\\framebreak B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch `\beamer@continueautobreak` so that it doesn't call `\frametitle` or `\framesubtitle`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@continueautobreak}{\frametitle}{\beamer@gobbleoptional}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@continueautobreak}{\framesubtitle}{\beamer@gobbleoptional}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\
\framebreak
B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\\framebreak B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it possible to do something similar if the first slide doesn't have a title? I want to get rid of the space at the top of the slide which is normally taken by the title in this case.

Comment: @user41974: If there is no title, then it doesn't take any space (at least in the default `beamer` theme), so I am not quite sure what you are asking. You can add the option `[t]` to the frame to get it to align at the top of the slide instead of the vertical center, if that helps?

Answer (score 4):

Redefine the template `frametitle continuation` to clear the current title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\
\framebreak
B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\\framebreak B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{New Title}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative via `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}`. Inspired by the fact that a simple `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}` still print the Title name, without numbering though. So print the Title again with white color.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\frametitle{\color{white}Title}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\
\framebreak

B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ 

\framebreak 
B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Not a title frame}
C\\C\\C\\C\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```